# How to allow incoming IPv6 traffic on OCI?

Tags: cloud, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I have got an default Ubuntu instance which I want to access from outside through IPv6.

I already did the following:

- Added an IPv6 CIDR Block
- Added an v6 address to the VNIC of the instance
- Changed the default routing table for the VCN to enable ::/0 traffic to the internet gateway
- Changed the outgoing security list to enable all v6 traffic
- Added an rule to allow ICMP incoming traffic from ::/0

Still I'm not able to ping the instance. Accessing stuff on the internet from the instance itself works fine (so e.g. I can do "ping -6 google.com")

I'm now really confused on what's left to do. Maybe it's something ob the Ubuntu system itself? I also did not find anything through googling sadly.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you allow the incoming ICMP rule in the security list of the OCI as well as on the OS firewall IPTABLE.

Comment: Hey @Anupam-Sinha! I've added the ICMP rule in the security list of the OCI for a source of ::/0, so that I guess should work. IPTABLE is another thing. There's ip6tables and iptables and even if I stop the services using "systemctl stop iptables && systemctl stop ip6tables" (only for dev-puposes!) it doesn't work. And I also added a rule using "sudo ip6tables -A INPUT -p ipv6-icmp -j ACCEPT" but still no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

I have the following setup:

- I have an Ubuntu instance in Oracle Cloud.
- I setup Networking > Virtual Cloud Networks > myVCN > Security List Details to allow only my IP to access the Ubuntu instance.

[image: Security List Details]

I am using dynamic IP broadband service. Usually I have to obtain my IPv4 by Google "[what is my ipv4](https://www.google.com/search?q=what%20is%20my%20ipv4)", then I'll copy it and manually update the new IPv4 to the Ingress Rules.

One time I went to Malaysia, I realize Google doesn't return me IPv4, but it returns IPv6?!

Then, I was forced to research how to enable IPv6 Ingress Rules for Oracle Cloud too.

Sorry, I did not manage to find out how to setup IPv6 Ingress Rules, but I found out:

1. https://www.whatismyip.com/ is showing me IPv4 and IPv6. I can still use the IPv4 value in the Ingress Rules and it works for me.
2. or in Oracle SSH terminal, execute **$ echo $SSH_CLIENT | cut -d' ' -f 1**, it also shows IPv4 that I am connecting from.

So, this none-technical solution may just work.